# Key Binds not working in PySimpleGUI App. How to add shortcut keybinds in app?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I am trying to build a simple textbox window which closes after pressing Enter key. I tried several approaches, but none worked. Here's the code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

init_layout = [
    [sg.Input('', size=(None, 5), background_color='white', border_width=0, key='-MULTILINE-')]
]

init_window = sg.Window('Enter File Name', init_layout, finalize=True)

while True:
    event, values = init_window.read()
    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, '\r'):
        break
```

When I press enter key, nothing happens...

I tried using '\r' and also 'Enter', but that didn't work.

Comment: You'll want to use a `Multiline` element instead of an `Input` element if you want an input that's 5 lines in height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're lot of ways to do it as following, then handle the event in your event loop.

1. Binding window with the event `'<Return>'` after window finalized.

```py
# "Return" event
window.bind("<Retrun>", "Return")
```

2. Binding the Input element with the event `'<Return>'` after window finalized.

```py
# "-INPUT- Return" event
window['-INPUT-'].bind("<Return>", " Return")
```

3. Add one hidden Button with `bind_return_key=True`.

```py
# "Enter" event
sg.Button('Enter', bind_return_key=True, visible=False)
```

4. Add option `return_keyboard_events=True` to `sg.Window`.

```py
# '\r' event or 'Return:13' (It maybe different for different platform)
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, return_keyboard_events=True)
```

Comment: I like the `bind_return_key=True` option  It's maybe the simplest.  Usually there's an OK /  Cancel button on windows that you can add it to or you can use an invisible one as Jason has shown.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `bind` function (to add Tkinter events to an element)

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

init_layout = [
    [sg.Input('', size=(None, 5), background_color='white', border_width=0, key='-MULTILINE-')]
]

init_window = sg.Window('Enter File Name', init_layout, finalize=True)
init_window.bind("<Return>","enter") # bind the <Return> event as "enter"
# note: "enter" is a name, it can be anything

while True:
    event, values = init_window.read()
    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, 'enter'): # use "enter" as the keybind
        break
```